# Launch url in flutter_widget_from_html

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

Using flutter_widget_from_html, my html is rendering, but the links are not launching.
I am using th url_launcher package and my code is below.

Am i doing something wrong?

```
 HtmlWidget('<p>This is a <a href="https://bbc.co.uk">link</a></p>', 
                onTapUrl: (url) => canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url)),
                renderMode: RenderMode.column,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`canLaunchUrl`](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/canLaunchUrl.html) is a function to check if the specified URL can be launched, and returns a boolean. To actually launch the URL, use [`launchUrl`](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html).

```dart
onTapUrl: (url) => launchUrl(Uri.parse(url)),
```